# How to run a project downloaded from github

Tags: wamp

I have downloaded a project from github ,when I try to run it the following error appears:

Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at wampserver@wampserver.invalid to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

---

Apache/2.4.51 (Win64) PHP/7.4.26 Server at localhost Port 80

and this is the link of the project:
https://github.com/JHurricane96/BusTrackerWeb

what’s the wrong ,and how can I open it?
please help me

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Well, I edited it @Filburt

Comment: Check the server logs to see what the real error is.

Comment: @AndyPreston thanks for replying I don’t know how to check it I think the error in apache,,I have this error:Your port '.80.' is actually used by :
Server: Apache/2.4.51 (Win64) PHP/7.4.26
Cannot install the Apache service, please stop this application and try again.
Press Enter to exit...

Answer (score -1):

1. Install Git In your System
2. install Git and Open Git bash
3. in git bash write command

   > git clone Git link
   > clone the Project

example :- git clone https://github.com/JHurricane96/BusTrackerWeb.git

Comment: thank you so much..I did this there is no errors appear in git bash but still not open @Pathak Mohit

Comment: not open means program not work / not execute